# Device not getting location after allow permission - React Native - Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am working with react native app, which totally depends on location, so I have created below code for it, in most of real device I am not able to get location, and always returns on error into granted condition with Alert box of cancel or try again

```
getLocation = () = {
    try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            'title': 'Permission Title',
            'message': 'App ' +
              'Message'
          }
        )
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            that = this;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    this.checkLogin(position);
                },
                (error) => {
                    Alert.alert(
                      'Location',
                      'We are not able to get your current location.',
                      [
                        {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp(), style: 'cancel'},
                        {text: 'Try Again', onPress: () => this.getLocation()},
                      ],
                      { cancelable: false }
                    )
                },
                { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 1000, distanceFilter: 1 }
            );
        } else {
          alert("Location permission denied")
        }
    }catch(err){
        alert(err)
    }
}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Is there any quick solution that works in all device or let me know if I have to update my above code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [this library](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation) for react native geolocation. It is a solid plugin that works right out of the box. You won't even need to do your own permission implementation. It does it for you. I use it for both my Android and iOS apps built in React Native. It can even be configured to work in the background!

Comment: www.transistorsoft.com/shop/customers `Unauthorized` -> I am not able to complete the setup for this plugin